# Applying focus styles to a parent element when a children input is selected but only with keyboard

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, css-selectors, storybook

So i've stumbled upon this issue twice now. I have custom components that sometimes need custom focuses and such.

For example, [this radio component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95zUM.png) needs to somehow make the radio button selected whilst actually setting focus on the parent wrapper. And when pressing enter, it should make the radio have `checked="true"`

This problem seems to be solvable with using `:has()` selector with CSS, but it's not widely supported, so I cannot use this.

While using :focus-within on the parent wrapper it almost works, but I also get the focused border `onClick`, which I don't want. I want it to be focusable by keyboard.

So my question is. Should I make the wrapper a component that passes `checked` state down to the `<input type="radio" />`, or can I somehow solve it using HTML and CSS and even typescript?

Comment: Not sure how `:has()` would help you here to begin with? It would still have to be something like `:has(input:focus)` - and then you still have the same problem, that clicking will give the field the focus, same as tabbing to it via the keyboard would.

Comment: @CBroe https://larsmagnus.co/blog/focus-visible-within-the-missing-pseudo-class this is something that I found related exactlyto my problem

Comment: Ah, okay, using `:focus-visible`, that makes sense. Using `:has()` can generally be avoided in a situation like this, by placing the radio button before the label, outside of it - so that the adjacent sibling combinator can be used, to modify the label styling based on the radio button state. If you wrap it all into a relative wrapper, so that you could _position_ the radio button within the label again, the same approach _might_ work, I suppose?

Comment: (The other usual approach for "custom radio buttons/ checkboxes", of hiding the radio button/ checkbox, and emulating it visually with a different element inside the label then, probably won't work here, because in that situation I don't think you will get `:focus-visible` to apply.)

Comment: yeah :focus-visible didn't work in this case for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally had to solve it by using typescript. So I'm listening to the current elements keyup event and detecting is the key pressed was Tab and applying `-is-focused` class to the wrapper.

I detect off element keypresses with a global event listener and if the targeted element is not current element, it takes the focus off.

```
const elemId = `${id}--wrapper`;
document.getElementById(elemId)?.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Tab') {
    document.getElementById(elemId)?.classList.add('is-focused');
  }
});
document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  const current = e.target as HTMLElement;

  if (current?.parentElement?.id !== elemId) {
    document.getElementById(elemId)?.classList.remove('is-focused');
  }
});
```

EDIT: The previous solution wasn't obviously very good and it's hard to test using jest. The coverage was absolutely horrible.

I found a library called [React-aria](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/useFocusRing.html#usefocusring) that finally gave me a helping hand. I'm currently using `useFocusRing()`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { useFocusRing } from 'react-aria';

  const { isFocusVisible, focusProps } = useFocusRing();

<div
  className={classNames('checkbox', {
    'is-focused': isFocusVisible,
  })}
>
 <input
   {...focusProps}
   type="checkbox"
 />
 
 </div>
```